# MediaPlayer BroadcastReceiver RuntimeException

Tags: android, media-player, broadcastreceiver, runtimeexception

I am having a bit of trouble with the MediaPlayer object in Android. Specifically, I am trying to play an m4a file from a url. On the surface it seems to be working fine, including properly playing the audio file. In my logcat however I am getting a steady stream of runtime exceptions. Specifically: "BroadcastReceiver trying to return result during a non-ordered broadcast"

I am confused about this since I never set up a broadcastreceiver anywhere in my code. My complete source code is as follows:

```
public class homeActivity extends Activity {
    private MediaPlayer player;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        player = new MediaPlayer();
        try {
            player.setDataSource("http://www.promoshuffle.com/fantrailTest/sample.m4a");
            player.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        player.start();
    }
}
```

For reference, I am debugging on a Motorolla Atrix, and as I said above, the audio is actually playing properly. If anyone has any thoughts on what might be causing this exception I would really appreciate it!  Thanks in advance.

Avtar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the error is not originating from your code, then perhaps you have nothing to worry about.

Having said that, try using prepareAysnc() instead of prepare().

You'll need to implement MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener and call player.start() in onPrepared() method.

Comment: Well, I tried prepareAsync but it didn't seem to help. That said, its not causing any other obvious problems so I think I don't have to worry. Thanks for the input!